# In C#, does an overriden property return the stored value to the parent class?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, return-value

I have a base page for an order form. Inside this base page are a few properties that are abstract. They are overriden in a child class. One property in particular is called CompanyName. It's a string. In the child class, I have added code that pulls the CompanyName from a collection of CompanyNames. Since the overriden property obtains a CompanyName, can the parent class access the value obtained by the child's class version of the method?

Here is a snippet of my parent class named OrderFormBasePage:

```
protected string GetNextInvoiceNumber()
        {
            using (NewUOCompany db = new NewUOCompany())
            {

            }

            var model = new InvoiceModel();
            return model.GetNextInvoiceNumber(CompanyID).ToString();
        }

        #region Properties
        protected int CompanyID { get; }
        protected abstract string CompanyName { get; }
        protected abstract string OutputFilename    { get; }
        protected abstract string SourcePDFPath     { get; }
        #endregion
```

Here is a snippet of the child class named GetEuropeanSubmissionForm:

```
public partial class GetEuropeanSubmissionForm : OrderFormBasePage
    {
        #region Properties
        protected override string CompanyName
        {
            get { return Constants.companyNames.EuropeanCompanyName; }
        }
        protected override string OutputFilename
        {
            get { return "Submission Form - Europe.pdf"; }
        }
        protected override string SourcePDFPath
        {
            get { return "~/pdf/" + OutputFilename; }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

So basically, when the user wants to download the European Form pdf, they are redirected to a GetEuropeanSubmissionForm page. The code behind will supply the right CompanyName and the right pdf. But the pdf needs to be modified to display the right CompanyName, CompanyID, and invoice number. I know how to do it by hardcoding a config file but this solution lets me manage the code in only one place instead of in many places. So if I want to write the code for the CompanyID retrieval inside of OrderFormBasePage, and if I want to search the database for the CompanyID that corresponds to the CompanyName pulled in GetEuropeanSubmissionForm, should OrderFormBasePage's CompanyName property now contain the CompanyName pulled by GetEuropeanSubmissionForm? I tried searching "C# overriden property returning value to parent class" but found no results. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Yes, when the base class accesses the properties , it will get the values that are set in the parent class.

Check this example, especially the area property and usage of it in Shape.ToString() method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd3z1377.aspx

Comment: If I attempt to use the CompanyName property in the using block inside of my OrderFormBasePage file, will the value for the CompanyName property be whatever was obtained in the GetEuropeanSubmissionForm file?

Comment: Yes, i have added a linqpad screenshot to prove it :-)

Comment: The picture helps a lot. The GetCompanyName() method returns this.CompanyName, meaning the CompanyName property from BaseOrderForm. So even though CompanyName is abstract in BaseOrderForm, it still returns the value from the EuropeanOrderForm. And if there was another form that was being called after the user clicked on a "Japanese form" button, like a JapaneseOrderForm, it'd return that page's CompanyName property, right? It makes sense now, I'm mostly just thinking out loud. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The whole point of overriding is that *all* calls to that member, no matter what type they're made through, call the overridden version.

Comment: So just to clarify, if I add a call to the CompanyName member INSIDE of the OrderFormBasePage, the CompanyName value returned is whatever was obtained by the GetEuropeanSubmissionForm page? That's what I'm hoping for with this move from config files to inherited properties and methods.

Comment: Yes; it will always call the overridden member, no matter where you're calling it from.

Answer (score 1):

This is the idea of polymorphic behavior, common denominator takes different shapes of behavior according to the actual instance behind it.